# How can we update a cell in Google Spreadsheet through a URL parameter?

Tags: google-sheets, url-parameters

I have a Google Spreadsheet that is intended for public access. However, I'd like to allow for URL parameter(s) through a user's browser that can help modify one or more cells of the spreadsheet before the entire spreadsheet is presented on the screen.
See [the example here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AgvcQSA3jj3ydGlQV2E4bndaaWNEbnVqbU5hbk1Va0E&hl=en).

Is something like this possible?
https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AgvcQSA3jj3ydGlQV2E4bndaaWNEbnVqbU5hbk1Va0E&hl=en?B4=8
Can something like the URL above succeed in changing B4 to 8 before the spreadsheet is presented to the requesting user?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453492/3525368

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798608/http-get-in-google-spreadsheet-e-undefined). The question 
I'm not sure if you can do it and open the spreadsheet with the same link (I've asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813699/open-google-spreadsheet-via-google-apps-script) about that too), but if you read the answer by Serge insas (on the first question linked), mainly edit 2, you'll see how to use `HTTP Get` to edit cells with a link.