# Use google-apps script url in project html

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a deployed web app from google sheets and I want to build a dynamic url in my html file that allows me to pass a parameter to the html file so it will update correctly.

As referenced in the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798608/http-get-in-google-spreadsheet-e-undefined) question/answer I've used this as part of my doGet function to allow for using part of the url to set a value within my spreadsheet.  This works fine.

```
function doGet(e){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TAB_NAME");
    var row = Number(e.parameter.row); 
    var col = Number(e.parameter.col); 
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, col);

    sheet.getRange(row, col).setValue('APPROVED')}
```

I'm sending an email that allows the user to click the url to allow for the cell to be updated.  I have the row and column hardcoded currently, and it performs the desired function (updating the cell) for that row and column.  I want to have a dynamic url string that allows me to build the url for different rows depending on the data.

```
<a href="https://script.google.com/. . ./exec?row=5&col=44" 
target="_blank" style="padding: 8px 12px; border: 1px solid 
#00AA00;border-radius: 2px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans- 
serif;font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;font- 
weight:bold;display: inline-block;"> APPROVE</a>
```

I also have this in my gs file.  How can I pass the value of Alast, which will give me the row that I want from my gs file to the html file?

```
var thisSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet_ID");
var s = thisSS.getSheetByName("View");
var Avals = s.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
```

Comment: Use templated html or standard client-server communication for Google Apps Script. The official documentation should cover this use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a function like this:

Google Script(Server Side):

```
function getScriptURL(qs) {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  //Logger.log(url + qs);
  return url + qs ;
}
```

and this client side:

```
function getUrl(qs){
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(loadNewPage)
  .getScriptURL(qs);
}
```

I load the new page with a command like this:

```
window.open(url,"_top");
```

I use this for navigating between pages and the `getURL(querystring)` is hardwired in to the navigation buttons but you can also get them from dynamic data either client side or server side.

Perhaps like this:

ClientSide Javascript:

```
function getUrl(){
  var r=$('#rv').val();
  var c=$('#cv').val();
  var qs={row:r,col:c};
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(msg){
      //not sure what you would want to do here if anything
  })
  .getScriptURL(qObj);
}
```

Server Side:

```
function getScriptURL(qObj) {
  var url = Utilities.formatString('%s?row=%s&col=%s',ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(),qObj.row,qObj.col);
  //Actually at this point I'd probably just update the data and forget about assembling a querystring to be sent back to the server.  And return a message to the user now it has been updated.
  //Logger.log(url + qs);
  return url;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I totally missed ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() before.  I was able to append the values based on the data being used and then passed that through the HTMLService.