# Open Google Spreadsheet via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to open a Google Spreadsheet via Google Apps script?
I'm trying to create a way to link to a certain cell in a spreadsheet, but I can't manage to open a sheet from a script (deployed as a web app).
I want to open the spreadsheet and then set the active sheet and range (I know how to do the latter, when the spreadsheet is opened).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Here's my current code:

```
function doGet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[id]");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Kunder");
  var row = Number(e.parameter.row); 
  var col = Number(e.parameter.col); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, col);

  //OPEN THE SPREADSHEET HERE

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the correct ID for the spreadsheet. One way to find it is:

1. Open the containing folder in Google Drive
2. Right-click the spreadsheet
3. Select Get link
4. Copy the URL shown

The URL will be in the form:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxo

Use the id parameter value as the argument to openById, e.g.:

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxoxo");

Comment: This doesn't actually open the file though.  According to the documentation: "// Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side."

Comment: The open function is completely useless since you can't modify anything on a spreadsheet if it's only "opened" on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Found this at https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/02/20/open-site-with-new-window-using-google-apps-script/

```js
function myFunction() {
  var js = " \
    <script> \
      window.open('https://tanaikech.github.io/', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600'); \
      google.script.host.close(); \
    </script> \
  ";
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
    .setHeight(10)
    .setWidth(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.'); // If you use this on Spreadsheet
//  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.'); //  If you use this on Document
//  SlidesApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now loading.'); //  If you use this on Slides
}
```

I altered the link and the window size so that it would simply open in a new tab (you could probably remove `'_blank'` as well...)

```js
      <script> \
        window.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + custFileID.id + "', '_blank'); \
        google.script.host.close(); \
      </script> \
```

`custFileID` is another function that finds the file ID.  Just replace that with your own variable or file ID.

Comment: what is _blank? Does it require using a special library?

Comment: That’s, afaik, just HTML to open the browser in a new window. Not library needed. You can also name the window in place of “_blank”.